# What's the preferred tool/plugin of choice to add search capabilities?

Tags: scala, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I'm building an application on top of Scala 2.12.x, Slick 3.3.0 & Playframework 2.7.x and require adding Web App indexing and searching capabilities. For now the search will only target static routes within the App but I can imagine in a no so distant future having to index/search over a database too.

There are multiple alternatives, some as simple as client-side plugins to dynamically search without using any indexes. A more robust approach would be employing [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) ... are there any sample integrations? plugins?

Any other alternatives worth considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scala-lucene-play-example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scala-lucene-play-example) is a small example demonstrating Lucene with Play.

Routes implementation:

```
@Singleton class ConditionsController @Inject()(
    cc: ControllerComponents,
    repo: ConditionsRepository
) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def exact(term: String) = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(repo.searchByExactTitle(term)))
  }

  def fuzzy(term: String) = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(repo.searchByFuzzyTitle(term)))
  }

  def phrase(term: String) = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(repo.searchByPhraseTitle(term)))
  }

  def wildcard(term: String) = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(repo.searchByWildcardTitle(term)))
  }

  def fulltext(term: String) = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(repo.searchByFullText(term)))
  }
}
```

Search logic

```
package repo

import com.outr.lucene4s._
import com.outr.lucene4s.DirectLucene
import com.outr.lucene4s.field.Field
import com.outr.lucene4s.field.value.FieldAndValue
import com.outr.lucene4s.query.{SearchResult, SearchTerm, Sort}
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

@Singleton class ConditionsRepository @Inject()(fileImporter: FileImporter) {
  private val lucene = new DirectLucene(
    uniqueFields = List("title"),
    defaultFullTextSearchable = true,
    autoCommit = true
  )
  private val title: Field[String] = lucene.create.field[String]("title")
  private val text: Field[String] = lucene.create.field[String]("text")
  initLucene()

  private def toFields(condition: Condition): Seq[FieldAndValue[_]] =
    Seq(title(condition.title.trim), text(condition.text))

  private def addToLucene(condition: Condition): Unit =
    lucene.doc().fields(toFields(condition): _*).index()

  private def initLucene(): Unit =
    fileImporter
      .asConditions()
      .foreach(addToLucene)

  private val exactTitle = title.apply _ andThen exact _
  private val fuzzyTitle = title.apply _ andThen fuzzy _
  private val phraseTitle = parseFuzzy(_ :String, Some(title))
  private val wildcardTitle = title.apply _ andThen wildcard _
  private val fulltext = lucene.fullText.apply _ andThen fuzzy _

  private def toCondition(result: SearchResult): Condition =
    Condition(result(title), result(text))

  private def search(term: String, searchFunc: String => SearchTerm): Vector[Condition] =
    lucene
      .query()
      .scoreDocs()
      .sort(Sort.Score)
      .filter(searchFunc(term.toLowerCase))
      .search()
      .pagedResultsIterator
      .toVector
      .map(toCondition)

  def searchByExactTitle(term: String): Vector[Condition] = search(term, exactTitle)
  def searchByFuzzyTitle(term: String): Vector[Condition] = search(term, fuzzyTitle)
  def searchByPhraseTitle(term: String): Vector[Condition] = search(term, phraseTitle)
  def searchByWildcardTitle(term: String): Vector[Condition] = search(term, wildcardTitle)
  def searchByFullText(term: String): Vector[Condition] = search(term, fulltext)
}
```

Lucene dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.outr" %% "lucene4s" % "1.8.1"
```